# internet resources for comment and advice on personal voice?

Tags: discussion

I would like someone to listen and comment on my voice. I know that there are voice coaches that can teach me some drills to improve my vocal habits, but I also would like to know some free internet websites where people can help to comment on my speaking or singing sample that I upload? I wonder if you know such websites? Does this site allow such discussion?

I also would like to hear opinions from medical perspective such as suspicion of some unusual anatomy of my vocal system.  I have heard of people having hypernasal, hypohasal or mixed problems due to different medical reasons.

Thanks!

Comment: You could always try youtube... alternatively, your best bet would probably be to try and find a vocal pedagogy forum of some kind, upload a file to soundcloud or youtube and solicit advice.

Comment: If you have a specific question about singing or want feedback on a specific aspect of your voice, Music.StackExchange would be a good place get feedback. For example, if you're not sure how to control how nasal your voice is, we could tell you how to do so.

Comment: We wouldn't be able to identify medical issues, though. For that, you would probably need to see a voice coach, singing instructor, or speech therapist.

Comment: Be careful what you 'correct' - you may be the next Bob Dylan ;-)

Comment: Hi Tim - we don't do opinions, and medical advice is really not going to be on topic here. Also, we don't do product or site recommendations. We can answer specific questions, and giving us a link to your track/sample can be useful. I'll move this to meta, though.